# delphi - coloring cxdbgrid field depending on its content

Tags: delphi, devexpress, delphi-xe4, tcxgrid

I am not exactly sure how to put this. I am coloring cxDB grid field based on the value:

```
procedure TForm1.cxGrid1DBTableView1StylesGetContentStyle(
  Sender: TcxCustomGridTableView; ARecord: TcxCustomGridRecord;
  AItem: TcxCustomGridTableItem; var AStyle: TcxStyle);
  var  AColumn: TcxCustomGridTableItem;
begin
AColumn := (Sender as TcxGridDBTableView).GetColumnByFieldName('SIFRA');
 if VarToStr(ARecord.Values[AColumn.Index]) =  '007 01' then
      AStyle := cxstyle1; 
end;
```

I would like to change the code so that all the fields that have 007 in the column get coloured.

Comment: Ok, better yet is to use `if StartsText('007', VarToStr(ARecord.Values[AColumn.Index])) then`.

Comment: your version colors all of my fields. I want only the selected 'sifra'

Comment: also StartsText is unreckognised

Comment: Add `System.StrUtils` to your `uses` clause. But your problem is not in that condition. You'll need to understand, how that event works. And that's what I can't help you with.

Comment: Both work the same way. I want to color the specific field in the grid containing 007. Both of your version color ALL of my fields. I dont need that.

Comment: I got your question as you're looking for a way to rewrite that `if` condition to apply for all values starting with `007`. That's all I proposed. I don't know anything about how that event works. You obviously need to get more than what you described as *"using of wildcards"*.

Comment: I need wildcards for that text after the 7:  =  '007 01' then

Comment: That line `if StartsText('007', SomeText) then` evaluates to `True` if the string in `SomeText` variable starts with `007`. So it could be something you may understand as `007*`. If that's what you've asked and it colors all the fields, then you'll need to do something else in that event method.

Comment: like i said, i dont want all the fields colored but only ones with 007 in them.

Comment: Ok, so then I got your question wrong. Can we delete our comments from here to cleanup the workspace, please ?

Comment: @TLama - I think these comments would serve as a precaution for anyone who would like to sort this out.

Comment: @Sertac, hm, that's right, but there's a lot of them. Maybe would be fine to include that `StartsText` line into the question. Or emphasize somehow that the way of using that event is wrong.

Comment: @TLama - It's your call, but indeed the first comment already answers the question (wildcards I mean).

Comment: I guess using Lamas suggestion can be done. Just added another style in style repository and fixed the issue.

Comment: -1 The comments address the question, but you complain that they do not. Your question is ill-stated. Fix the question to be clear what you are asking.

Comment: Lama,please post the answer since the first suggestion could do.Thank you !

Comment: user - You can address a commentator like @TLama (note the @ and correct usage of the account name), then the commentator will be notified.

Comment: @TLama - Please post the answer,,,T

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to comments, you were looking for a way how to write a statement to determine if a certain text starts with a specified string. For this you can use e.g. the [`StartsText`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/2010/en/StrUtils.StartsText) function (`System.StrUtils`). The following statement will evaluate to True if the current cell text starts with `007`:

```
if StartsText('007', VarToStr(ARecord.Values[AColumn.Index])) then
```