# cxgrid color numbers in the grid using styles

Tags: delphi, devexpress, tcxgrid

I would like to apply a style to a column (on get content style) so all numbers in that column color to the selected style. Just the numbers, nothing else.That means that if a number is found within a text phrase it will get colored. Is this possible ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [delphi - coloring cxdbgrid field depending on its content](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20183431/delphi-coloring-cxdbgrid-field-depending-on-its-content)

Comment: Isn't this the same question you asked earlier? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20183431/delphi-coloring-cxdbgrid-field-depending-on-its-content?rq=1

Comment: @SamM similar but not the same....Now I want the numbers found in the text to get colored, leaving the text intact.

Comment: In your style object, what properties are you setting? Posting the object's definition from your dfm file would be very helpful.

Comment: just text color :clred for the style nothing else...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. Use something like

```
procedure TForm1.Column1StylesGetContentStyle(
  Sender: TcxCustomGridTableView; ARecord: TcxCustomGridRecord;
  AItem: TcxCustomGridTableItem; var AStyle: TcxStyle);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  if TryStrToInt(ARecord.Values[Column1.Index], i) then
    AStyle := cxStyle1;
end;
```

Comment: I tried : if  StrToInt('123') then... but [dcc32 Error] Unit3.pas(140): E2012 Type of expression must be BOOLEAN

Comment: if I use . if  TryStrToInt('123456',0) then ... I get [dcc32 Error] Unit3.pas(140): E2250 There is no overloaded version of 'TryStrToInt' that can be called with these arguments ... maybe I am just messing up....

Comment: @user763539, The second parameter of TryStrToInt must be a variable, not a constant. You are passing it a constant (0) which is why you get the compiler error.

Comment: @Sam M How am I supposed to write it ?

Comment: var i:integer; and TryStrToInt(123,i) colors everything in the column. I want just the numbers.

Answer (score 0):

This is rough code but ought to get you in the right direction. I think it may overlap your drawing a little on the canvas but you can adjust where needed. You will also need to adjust so that it parses out the numbers from the strings.

```
procedure TForm7.cxGrid1TableView1CustomDrawCell(Sender: TcxCustomGridTableView;
  ACanvas: TcxCanvas; AViewInfo: TcxGridTableDataCellViewInfo;
  var ADone: Boolean);
var Bounds : TRect;
begin
  Bounds := AViewInfo.Bounds;

  ACanvas.Font.Color := clRed;
  ACanvas.TextOut(Bounds.Left, Bounds.Top, '123');
  Bounds.Left := ACanvas.Canvas.TextWidth('123');

  ACanvas.Font.Color := clGreen;
  ACanvas.TextOut(Bounds.Left, Bounds.Top, 'abc');

  ADone := True;
end;
```

Comment: it distorted all of my text into 123 ...only click in the cell shows the underlying text.